# Compilation failed for type int(&)const

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

`int()const` does not make sense for free function but is allowed in `c++` type system.

Why do `int(&)()const` & `int(&&)()const` cause following compilation error on `Clang` provided `int()const` is allowed:

```
<source>:19:79: error: reference to function type cannot have 'const' qualifier
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<int()const>, int(&)()const>);
                                                                              ^
1 error generated.
```

`int()const` compiles fine

```
int main(void) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<int()const>, int()const>);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/61bh5417K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **possible implementation** of [`std::is_member_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_pointer). Now consider [pointers to member function](https://std::is_member_function_pointer)s(e.g. `void (C::*)()const`); how is the trait supposed to work with cv qualified member functions?
Primary answer was [abominable function types](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html). They are types that cannot be instantiated.

Now see the possible implementation of [`std::is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function). It is `true` for ordinary free(static) functions, as well as abominable function types. As you see in the link, there are possible implementations: the short one relies on the fact that free function types do not accept cv or references qualifiers; The entailed qualifiers show properties of `*this`, if the abominable functions are used as the signature of instance members of a class.

Roses are red, violets are blue... Calling conventions strike. Calling conventions are none standard extension present on almost all C++ platforms. For lots details that I can't mention here, the neat short ***possible implementation*** of `std::is_member_pointer` fails for member pointers with calling conventions. Now we are back to the cave we were trying to get out; `std::is_member_pointer` is defined with `24*N` specializations on each platform, with N == total number of calling conventions.

Function pointers and member pointers lie in one dark conrner of C++ programming, that we tend to prevent new programmers from dealing. But now that you're playing there, you'd better beware of their problems.

Answer (score 1):

`int () const` needs to be allowed because it's a part of member function pointer types. Something like `int (C::*)() const` translates to `T C::*` with `using T = int () const;`.

Also, given `using T = int () const;`, you can declare (but not define) class members using it: `T foo;` translates to `int foo() const;`.

There's no reason for `int (&)() const` or `int (&&)() const` to be allowed, because you can only have references to non-member functions (and those can't be `const`).

Answer (score 1):

> `int()`const does not make sense

It does make sense once you know that it is used in the syntax of member functions. For example:

```
struct C
{
    using type = int()const; //see it does make sense
    type func;
};
int main()
{
    C c;
    c.func(); 
}
```

---

> Why do `int(&)()const` & `int(&&)()const` cause following compilation error on Clang

Because the standard specifically prohibits this as per [dcl.mptr](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.mptr#4):

> The type “pointer to member” is distinct from the type “pointer”, that is, a pointer to member is declared only by the pointer to member declarator syntax, and never by the pointer declarator syntax. **There is no “reference-to-member” type in C++.**

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasised part. In particular, `int()const` is the syntax used for member functions and the standard does not allow a reference-to-member type.